# How to make Chrome URL display spaces instead of %20

Tags: google-chrome, url, character-encoding

Browsers like Firefox display URLs containing spaces (including nbsp's) with an actual space (); Chrome always displays spaces as `%20` (and nbsp's as `%C2%A0`) in the address bar. (ie, Firefox displays `http://example.com/A B` in the address bar while Chrome displays `http://example.com/A%20B`.) Is there any way to make Chrome display spaces as  instead of `%20`?

Comment: I'd like to have configuration for that too <3

Answer (score 0):

If you can do with underscores instead of spaces (like in my case, where I only need to improve the readability of the URL), you can use:

```
window.history.pushState("string", "Title", window.location.href.replace(new URL(window.location.href, location).origin+'/', '').replaceAll('%20','_'))
```

(the last `replaceAll` could be an space instead of an underscore but Chrome would replace it with %20 anyway)

Maybe this could be done better with a Chrome extension.